# Excel - opening file stuck on 100%, until VBA code finishes

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Workbook_Open` event, which fires a script with lots of code. It runs very long (getting data from web) and I would like Excel to open the file while it runs, this VBA also shows progress on status bar. I use loops and `DoEvents` has been used on each iteration with no effect. Only when macro executes successfully or I use Ctrl + Pause Break, file opens. Any ideas what can be wrong and how it could be fixed?

Edit: I didn't attach the code, as I am not the author and there are hundreds of lines in it. I had hope of finding a general cause why such situation would happen, from someone who encountered similar.
Important: it appears that the initial version of the file which I received from colleague works correctly until I save the file, so there isn't any "bug" in the code. Using VBADebugger didn't help. There are no external connections and names in the file.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by letting VBA excecute `Workbook_Open` event ASAP. I put the whole earlier content of `Private Sub Workbook_Open` under "scraper" procedure and now it looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "scraper"
End Sub
```

It must be that Excel won't (sometimes?) open the file before executing Workbook_Open event.